# Google-styled theme for Bootstrap throwing a lot of CSS validation error. Is it safe to use the style-sheet?

Tags: html, css, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the [Google-styled theme for Bootstrap](http://todc.github.io/todc-bootstrap/) for one of my project. However, I  started noticing lately that the project website in itself has [300+ css validation errors](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://todc.github.io/todc-bootstrap/&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) - which is making use of todc-bootstrap.min.css stylesheet and so do my new website.

Is it good to push the site with current style-sheet to production? What will be harmful effect in performance if I have to migrate the code to production?

Answer (score 1):

You get validation errors, because this is crossbrowser css with legacy selectors, filter, and more. Its naturally. Just use it! :)